# Add passport tag?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tagging

There is a [visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visa) tag, but no [passport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/passport) tag. Should it be created?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Anyone with 150 rep or more can create a tag (that is, about 85 people including moderators).

However, the best way to create tags is to wait until there's a question that really needs it—tags that aren't attached to questions just get deleted.

Comment: I don't expect there would be as many questions about [tag:passport]s as about [tag:visa]s or [tag:passport-stamps] but it wouldn't hurt to create it if we get another question or two (the first is the US passport renewal question). Well somebody has indeed created it for that very question (-:

Comment: Creating a new tag now requires 300 reputation.